# Estimating the number of times a coin was flipped

Tags: probability

- Suppose there is are 100 students in a classroom
- There is a single coin with probability of success $p$
- Each student is handed the coin and flips the coin $n$ times (i.e. each student flips the coin exactly the same number of times)
- After a student is done, they write down the number of Heads they got

Based on this information (e.g. student1 = 5 heads, student2 = 13 heads, etc.) - how can we estimate  $p$ and $n$? i.e. the probability of getting a heads and the number of times the coin was flipped?

**Had we known $n$, then $p$ could have been solved simply using maximum likelihood estimation - but when you have to estimate both $n$ and $p$, how can this be done?**

Here is my attempt to solve this using Maximum Likelihood Estimation:

- Step 1: (Log) Likelihood Function (the sum is over each student)

  $$L(n, p | x) = \prod_{i=1}^{100} \binom{n}{x_i} p^{x_i} (1-p)^{n-x_i},$$

  $$l(n, p | x) = \sum_{i=1}^{100} \left[ \log \binom{n}{x_i} + x_i \log p + (n-x_i) \log (1-p) \right].$$
- Step 2: Derivatives

  $$\frac{\partial l}{\partial p} = \sum_{i=1}^{100} \left[\frac{x_i}{p} - \frac{n - x_i}{1 - p}\right],$$

$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial n} = 100 \log(1 - p) + \sum_{i=1}^{100} \frac{\partial}{\partial n} \log\binom{n}{x_i}.$$

- Step 3: Gamma Function and Binomial Coefficient equivalence:

$$\binom{n}{x} = \frac{\Gamma(n + 1)}{\Gamma(x + 1)\Gamma(n - x + 1)},$$

$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial n} = 100*log(1 - p) + \sum_{i=1}^{100} \frac{\partial}{\partial n} \log\left(\frac{\Gamma(n + 1)}{\Gamma(x_i + 1)\Gamma(n - x_i + 1)}\right).$$

- Step 4: Derivative of the Gamma Function (Digamma Function, $\psi$):

$$\begin{equation} \frac{\partial l}{\partial n} = 100*log(1 - p) + \sum_{i=1}^{100} \frac{\partial}{\partial n} \log \left(\frac{\Gamma(n + 1)}{\Gamma(x_i + 1)\Gamma(n - x_i + 1)}\right). \end{equation}$$

$$\begin{equation} \frac{\partial}{\partial n} \log \left(\frac{\Gamma(n + 1)}{\Gamma(x_i + 1)\Gamma(n - x_i + 1)}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial n} \left[\log \Gamma(n + 1) - \log \Gamma(x_i + 1) - \log \Gamma(n - x_i + 1)\right]. \end{equation}$$

$$\begin{equation} \frac{\partial l}{\partial n} = 100*log(1-p) + \sum_{i=1}^{100} \left[\psi(n + 1) - \psi(n - x_i + 1)\right]. \end{equation}$$

- Step 5: Final estimating equations:

  $$\sum_{i=1}^{100} \left[\frac{x_i}{\hat{p}_{\text{mle}}} - \frac{n - x_i}{1 - \hat{p}_{\text{mle}}}\right] = 0,$$

  $$100* log({1-\hat{p}_{\text{mle}}}) + \sum_{i=1}^{100} \left[\psi(\hat{n}_{\text{mle}} + 1) -\psi(\hat{n}_{\text{mle}} - x_i + 1)\right] = 0.$$

**My Question:** Have I done this correctly? And if so, are there any numerical algorithms which are meant for optimization problems involving the derivatives of Gamma Functions?

Thanks!

**Note:** I think this might be easier with Method of Moments?

For a binomial distribution, the first two moments are:

1. The expected value (mean) is $E[X] = np$.
2. The variance is $Var[X] = np(1-p)$.

If the sample mean as $\bar{x}$ and the sample variance as $s^2$ -  we can write:

1. $\bar{x} = np$,
2. $s^2 = np(1-p)$.

$$p = \frac{\bar{x}}{n}.$$

$$s^2 = n\left(\frac{\bar{x}}{n}\right)(1-\frac{\bar{x}}{n}) = \bar{x}(1-\frac{\bar{x}}{n}).$$

Solving for $n$ gives the method of moments estimate of $n$, $\hat{n}_{\text{mom}}$:

$$\hat{n}_{\text{mom}} = \frac{\bar{x}^2}{\bar{x} - s^2}.$$

With $\hat{n}_{\text{mom}}$, substitute it to get the method of moments estimate of $p$, i.e. $\hat{p}_{\text{mom}}$:

$$\hat{p}_{\text{mom}} = \frac{\bar{x}}{\hat{n}_{\text{mom}}} = \frac{\bar{x} - s^2}{\bar{x}}.$$

Perhaps this is also correct? (https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=sOXgFHWHchU)

Note: I  have heard that in Method of Moments, its possible that $\hat{n}_{\text{mom}}$ might be less than than the maximum number of successes observed in your data?

Comment: None of your work is correct.  You have completely failed to account for the fact that you have a finite sample of size $100$, hence your likelihood is a function of each student's reported number of heads, not just a single $x$.

Comment: @heropup : my apologies, i will restart and try again. would you like me to delete this question or leave it here? thanks

Comment: When taking the partial w.r.t. $n$, I am not sure where you get $\log \frac{p}{1-p}$. It seems like you took the partial w.r.t. $x$?

Comment: @angryavian : yes, I realize all the derivatives are wrong. should i delete this question and restart? or should I keep it as is?

Comment: @heropup I considered attacking the problem, but the best that I could come up with is to get the expected value of $~n,~$ as a function of $~p,~$ or vice-versa.  Is the goal of getting the expected value of *both* $~n~$ and $~p,~$ even meaningful?  If so, how would it be done?

Comment: I have made some changes - is my work now correct?